# Refused to apply style from 'url' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: php, hosting, mime

Tengo el siguiente problema al cargar los `assets`en un sitio que he subido a `000webhost`

> Refused to apply style from
>   'https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/ligne.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

**Este es el sitio:**
https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/clientes/todosClientes/

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que esto es un framework propio de PHP, genero las url de los `assets` de la siguiente manera;

```
<link href="<?= Assets::setAssets('css/ligne.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?= Assets::setAssets('css/font-awesome.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Esto me retorna lo siguiente;

```
<link href="https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/ligne.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`Assets::setAssets`

```
/**
 * Recibe un string con el elemento que se pretende agregar al proyecto
 *      eje: 'css/main.css'
 *      eje: 'js/jquery.min.js'
 * Este retorna una url absoluta
 * Tiene parametro opcional para determinar si se permitida que el navegador
 * almacene la cache de los assets
 *
 * @param $asset
 * @param bool $cache
 * @return string
 */
static public function setAssets($asset,$cache = true)
{
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $assets_dir = 'webassets';
    return PROTOCOL . '://' . $domain . '/' . self::root_dir() . '/' . $assets_dir . '/' . $asset . self::cache($cache);
}

/**
 * Retorna el nombre de la carpeta base del proyecto
 * esto es relativo ya que la carpeta donde esta el framework podria
 * llamarse de cualquier manera y con esto se obtiene este nombre para
 * hacer referencia a los assets
 *
 * @return string
 */
static private function root_dir(){
    $root_dir = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $root_dir = explode('/',$root_dir);
    return $root_dir[1];
}

/**
 * Se utiliza para retornar el tiempo a la url de los assets para
 * evitar que el navegador almacene estos en cache
 *
 * @param $bool
 * @return string
 */
static private function cache($bool){
    if(!$bool){
        return '?' . time();
    }
}
```

He intentado lo siguiente sin tener exito;

- Agregar `<base href="/">`antes de todos los assets
- Colocar la URL absoluta
- Mover los archivos a otro directorio
- Cambiar el mime type a `text/html`

mi ultima carta es preguntar a la comunidad.

**Edición:**

En local esto funciona perfecto, inclusive puedo acceder a los assets mediante la url;

`http://localhost/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/ligne.css`

Comment: Cuales serian las configuraciones ?porque si te refieres a  `apache` no creo que pueda tener acceso a esas configuraciones ya que es un servicio de host gratuito...imagínate :/ @Trauma

Comment: Lo más probable es que uno de los ficheros (si no ambos) no sea encontrado (404) y el servidor web te está mostrando la página de error 404 (de ahí el mime type). Puedes acceder manualmente a las urls del css generados ?

Comment: @Muriano obtengo 404, como por ejemplo ` https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/ligne.css ` creo que alguna configuración me falta o mi poca experiencia con estos servicios me esta afectando.

Comment: Este framework tuyo... `Assets::setAssets('css/ligne.css')` qué hace? dónde guarda el archivo generado?

Comment: @Muriano el método estático genera una `URL` según los datos pasados ya que las rutas serán relativas, de igual manera la definición del método esta en la pregunta.

Comment: No basta con generar una URL, tiene que "haber algo en esa URL", bien porque el fichero exista físicamente, o bien porque vía servidor web hagas una rescritura hasta un controlador que genere el contenido.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86022/discussion-between-albert-hidalgo-and-muriano).

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema con 000webhost, ya descarté las mayúsculas y minúsculas, y el problema persiste

Comment: @Koy Revisa la cache, intenta abrir en incógnito luego de descartar las mayúsculas y minúsculas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, el problema es que el servidor es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas;

La carpeta `webassets` la tengo con la W mayuscula en el servidor.

Answer (score 2):

No me ha servido nada de lo que todos comentan, la solucion ha sido arreglar las rutas ya que desde la página principal encontraba el archivo pero cuando navegaba desaparecía, la solucion correcta diría de tener estas cosas bien colocadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas en SO en español por favor responde en español, además en código debe ir como texto

Answer (score 2):

Hace poco, tuve el mismo error en con sitio alojado en Netlify.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultó ser un problema con la configuración de `cache-control`. Específicamente en `max-age=419200`
Se solucionó reduciendo a `max-age=0`

Answer (score 1):

Si abres tu página con la consola verás que los CSS y JS no se cargan. Ninguno. Dan error `404` y el servidor manda una pequeña página HTML informando del error, con lo que el MIME type se establece a `text/html`.

Intenta cargar este enlace y verás que no funciona:

https://ucrmreportcustom.000webhostapp.com/ucrm_client_report/webassets/css/ligne.css

Comment: Así es obtengo `404` en todo lo demás inclusive el favicon

Comment: Algún planteamiento ? configuración que deba hacer en `000webhost` o recomendación ?

Comment: Eso será específico de 000webhost. Mira su documentación. Lo siento pero no puedo ayudarte más.